# Determining p and link function for Tweedie distribution

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, tweedie-distribution

I am trying to model mean monthly plankton values across a timeseries with a generalized additive model.  My initial model was as follows:

```
library(mcgv)
m <- gam(phyto ~ s(YEAR, bs = "tp", k = 10) +    # smooth for trend across years
                 s(Month, bs = "cc", k = 12) +   # cyclic smooth so values in Dec line up with Jan
                 s(mSE, bs = "tp", k = 10) +     # smooth for solar elevation 
                 mLat + mLon,                    # linear terms for latitude and longitude
                 data = df, method = "REML", control = gam.control(nthreads = 4)
```

However, when I look at the model diagnostic plots, it appears that this is not a very good fit for the data.

```
library(gratia)
appraise(m)
```

[image]

A colleague suggested using a Tweedie distribution instead of the Guassian distribution, because my data does have a "peak" of values around 0 (note: a log transformation was applied to the mean values (+1 for 0's) and the logged values are used in the GAM above).

[image]

I've looked into Tweedie, but I'm unclear on how to select the p and if using a power link function, how to choose lambda. Can anyone provide advice on moving forward?

Comment: 1. "my data does have a "peak" of values around 0 (note: a log transformation was applied to the mean values and the logged values are used in the GAM above)." ...  if there were any $0$,s how did you still have 0's after taking logs? As $\epsilon\to 0$, $\log(\epsilon)\to -\infty$.  Conversely if there weren't exact 0's, why Tweedie? $\,$ 2. Having fitted Tweedie GLMs a few times, assuming exact 0's, I'd have probably looked at a zero-inflated model first, perhaps a zero-inflated gamma.

Comment: The problem with Tweedie is you need the parameter ($p$ in Wikipedia's parameterization, $\xi$ in Dunn & Smyth's) two do two distinct things: (i) to some a particular proportion of exact 0's you need very specific values of the parameter near 1, (ii) to match a variance-function you typically need very different values of the parameter. There's an additional issue in that with parameter values in the region where you get reasonable numbers of 0's, you tend to get "banding" at small values; the density of the continuous part oscillates, sometimes pretty wildly.

Comment: @Glen_b I'll clarify it in my question, but before taking the log, I added 1 to all of the values. Unfortunately, I don't see an option for a zero-inflated gamm in the mcgv package.

Comment: @Glen_b, so I guess my question is how to figure out what a good 'p' value is for my dataset.

Comment: With mgcv's `tw()` family you *don't* need to identify the value of $p$ as an outer iteration will search for the optimal value of this parameter. Noting @Glen_b's points about needing $p$ to do multiple things, my experience is similar too. If so and assuming you have enough data, try the `twlss()` family which would allow you to model $p$ and the scale parameter (instead of them being constants). Also, are these real zeroes? It seems like you have continuous response and perhaps the 0s are really censored? That would also suggest the zero-altered gamma or a censored gamma (see brms pkg)

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson. twlss() does work with my data, but it doesn't improve the model as much as I hoped. The 0's are probably not real 0's. The 0s are mean phytoplankton counts, and it's highly unlikely that there were exactly 0 phytoplankton in the samples, just that the values were so small that they were not observed.